# Slow file upload: Can I remove file attachment from multipart POST data on the fly and just submit form text fields?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, upload, websphere

I have a regular JSP/Servlet/Java web application that is used for uploading pictures from a mobile device.  I am using Apache Commons library for the upload.  Application is hosted on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.

Everything is working fine and the user can upload several images totaling 8MB or more if he has a really good/strong signal/connection or on a good WiFi.

The problem arises when the user is at a location with poor 3G/4G signal/connection. He gets errors like "Illegal state exception" or some time-out error, and in some cases the mobile browser just stays on the submit page with the progress bar no longer moving.

Any suggestions on how to "gracefully" handle this?  Like is there a way to intervene after a set amount of time and give the the user an option to submit the form without the file attachment (i.e. just submit the form text fields)?  Any other suggestions are welcome too.

**UPDATE:** The setTimeout solution below worked for me. The other missing piece was that I have to issue a "browser stop" command to stop the original submission that's in progress before I can issue a re-submit.  Otherwise, my re-submit command will just be ignored by the browser.

Comment: any conf parameter you can tune to extend the timeout?

Comment: Session timeout is set to 30 mins in WAS7.  But what I'm looking for is a way to intervene in the middle of the upload way before the session times out.  Like say, after 10 mins if the file is still uploading, I'll show a dialog and give him the option to submit the form without the file attachment.

Comment: most browsers will not read from server until the entire request is sent, so what you want to do is going to be pretty difficult.

Comment: @irreputable nah, not true. let me answer that :)

Comment: @naugtur - yes, client magic is needed to achieve it.

Comment: @irreputable Yeah, that's programming just like any other. It's high time Java developers started treating JS seriously. They simply need itif they want their web applications to be any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usecase here is simple - if the upload didn't finish in N minutes, remove/clear the field using javascript and resend the form.

You don't need to control the upload in the basic implementation, just safely asume that if you set a timeout to resend, it won't happen if the first attempt was successful and the page reloaded.

jQuery pseudocode:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $imageFieldNode.remove();
  $form.trigger('submit');
},30000);//after 30 seconds
```

The more advanced way is to use a ready solution for controlled upload. They work like that:

1. upload starts
2. js prompts the server in intervals with a GET query to get the size of content that was already received.
3. everytime it gets the info - it reports progress.

You can do a lot with these libs.

Comment: I just tried the setTimeout approach where I clear the image file elements from the form and trigger a re-submit.  Problem is the second submit attempt doesn't affect or is not cancelling the original submit.  The upload still continues and the original/unmodified POST data is still the one submitted.

Comment: Update: I just have to issue a "browser stop" command before I fire the re-submit.

Comment: Yeah, or you can use AJAX and `window.location.href=somewhere` after it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about the approach used in popular webmail clients (when attaching files to a message):

The files are uploaded independently (i.e. before) of the form submit, using javascript. Each of the files are stored in a temporary directory, and after the upload succeeds the user can proceed with the action.
The upload status is displayed to the user, and if it fails the main action (form fill/submit) does not get interrupted.